# Count the number of 1's in a list that contains two sets of 1's that are separated by 0's

Tags: xpath

I have two sets of 1's separated by some number of 0's. Before the first set of 1's is an arbitrary number of 0's and after the second set of 1's is an arbitrary number of 0's. Below is a sample instance. I need an XPath 2.0 expression that returns the number of 1's in the first set. And, I need an XPath 2.0 expression that returns the number of 1's in the second set of 1's. For the below sample instance, the first XPath expression should return 2, and the second XPath expression should return 3.

```
<Cells>
    <cell>
        <value>0</value>
    </cell>
    <cell>
        <value>1</value>
    </cell>
    <cell>
        <value>1</value>
    </cell>
    <cell>
        <value>0</value>
    </cell>
    <cell>
        <value>1</value>
    </cell>
    <cell>
        <value>1</value>
    </cell>
    <cell>
        <value>1</value>
    </cell>
    <cell>
        <value>0</value>
    </cell>
</Cells>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is going to look a little convoluted, but I think it may do the trick. The key here is [using the intersect() method](http://saxon.sourceforge.net/saxon7.9/expressions.html#except):

For the first expression, try:

```
 count(((//cell[value=1][following-sibling::cell[1][value=0] ][1]/(self::cell,preceding-sibling::cell[value=1])))

 intersect

(//cell[value=1][preceding-sibling::cell[1][value=0] ][1]/(self::cell,following-sibling::cell[value=1])))
```

and it outputs `2`.

The second expression just looks for the second group (note where `[1]` is changed to `[2]`):

```
  count(((//cell[value=1][following-sibling::cell[1][value=0] ][2]/(self::cell,preceding-sibling::cell[value=1])))

     intersect

    (//cell[value=1][preceding-sibling::cell[1][value=0] ][2]/(self::cell,following-sibling::cell[value=1])))
```

and it outpus `3`.

Basically, each expression looks for the groups of cells which have a `value` of `1` which either follow a cell with a `value` of `0` or are followed by one such cell, and then look for the intersection of those cells - that is, cells which both follow and are followed by a `0` value cell. There are two groups of such cells and the `count()` method counts them for each such group. Finally, the target group is selected by using the positional predicate `[1]` or `[2]` in the appropriate place.